# using leaflet-popup-angular with ionic application

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, leaflet

I am using [this](https://github.com/grantHarris/leaflet-popup-angular) library for my ionic app. When I use leaflet-popup-angular with ionic,when I click the circle the popup doesn't work.and gives me this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`.This errors sign this line  inside the L.Popup.Angular.js library file.->>

```
var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope'),
            $compile = $injector.get('$compile'),
            $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope) {
 var map = L.map('map', { zoomControl: false });
var noControllerPopup = L.popup.angular({
    template: `Hello world`,
}).setContent('But we can still use templates and $content.');
L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5
}).addTo(map).bindPopup(noControllerPopup);
```

//my Tile...

});
can u please help me to solve this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Update to version 1.0.1. Just released on bower and npm. The older versions assumed that you had your ng-app on the root html tag. This one looks for ng-app directly.